# Using Thread in Sync WireTap

Tags: threadpool, spring-integration, weblogic12c

I our application we plan to make wire-tap as Async call but we set some login information in the SecurityContext so if we make wire-tap as Async we will loose this data so we plan to go with the Synch Channel for Wire-tap and in the Interceptor class when we log we call a Thread to log the message in the DB.

What may be the impact with this approach is there any Thread poll limit we need to take care or is there any alternative solution for this?

We are using weblogic 12c

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should take care about `SecurityContext propagation`  (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2166). Please, read all those comments carefully.

You can add that `ChannelInterceptor`  the channel of your `wire-tap` and that separate thread will get `SecurityContext`.

For comprehensive answer I'm adding that `interceptor` code here:

```
class SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        if (!(channel in AbstractPollableChannel) || message.headers.securityContext || !SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication) return message

        return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).with {
            setHeader 'securityContext', SecurityContextHolder.context
            build()
        }
    }

    @Override
    Message<?> postReceive(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        if (channel in AbstractPollableChannel && message.headers.securityContext) {
            SecurityContextHolder.context = message.headers.securityContext
        }
        return message
    }

}
```